# How can I use Gestures on Mono/c# on Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, mono, gesture-recognition

I'm developing an app targeting Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) with Mono/C#. I've built my WinForm app in VS 2012/Win7 and it runs on Mono/Linux properly, so far so good but the problem is now I need to add touch/gesture (i.e: swipe, tap, rotate, and most important pinch) functionality in my app. How can I get these functions?

Thank you